# Type is not assignable to type - ts(2416)

Tags: typescript

I have the following interface and type (simplified):

```
type MyOwnColorType = "red" | "blue";

interface Title {
  id: string;
  color: MyOwnColorType;
}

export interface Example {
  title: Title;
}
```

If i try to create a class using this interface it will throw the ts 2416 error:

```
class JustAExample implements Example {  
  title = {
    id: "value",
    color: "red",
  }
}
```

It works if i cast it but that kind of defeats the purpose:

```
class JustAExample implements Example {  
  title = {
    id: "value",
    color: "red" as MyOwnColorType,
  }
}
```

Normally I would just state the type but considering it's a literal object I honestly just don't know the syntax for it. If I would put in a number for the id field it would state that wrong value is used so it does work as intended.

How can I make sure that the color is the given type?

Comment: You can annotate the `title` field like [this](https://tsplay.dev/Nd2byW); does that approach meet your needs? If so I could write up an answer explaining (and why `implements Example` unfortunately has no effect); if not, what am I missing?

Comment: Might be better to give the full code so I can explain it better. 

https://github.com/marcojanssen/drunagor-helper/blob/8b25679abfc3953c5e427d52dee32728fe2d0c87/src/data/content/spoilsofwar/monster/WalkingHorror.ts

implements

https://github.com/marcojanssen/drunagor-helper/blob/8b25679abfc3953c5e427d52dee32728fe2d0c87/src/data/store/MonsterData.ts

This line:

https://github.com/marcojanssen/drunagor-helper/blob/8b25679abfc3953c5e427d52dee32728fe2d0c87/src/data/content/spoilsofwar/monster/WalkingHorror.ts#L29

Should only allow top or bottom as value. If i remove the as it fails

Comment: Does a `const` assertion like [this](https://tsplay.dev/NrDYoW) work better for you? I'm happy to write up an answer if so; let me know.

Comment: Provided answer did the trick. Thanks for replying @jcalz